# How to override update_password.jsp in Liferay DXP 7.3.10 GA1

Tags: jsp, module, liferay-7

I am trying to override the portal-web page `update_password.jsp` following these examples:

- [JSP Overrides Using Custom JSP Bag](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029122491-JSP-Overrides-Using-Custom-JSP-Bag) and
- [this example from Dave Nebinger](https://github.com/dnebing/jsonws-style-override)

I also set the property *service.ranking:Integer=112* in my *CustomJspBag* subclass.
My module deploys and starts without errors and the page in *portal-web/docroot/html/portal/update_password.jsp* is replaced by the new one and the old page becomes *update_password.portal.jsp*.
The class gets activated and the `getCustomJsps()` returns the page name.

But the changes are not visible in the browser. The old page keeps showing.
How can I make it work?

Comment: Hi @Luke, could you please provide the Liferay version that you are using? Is it Liferay DXP CE  7.2.1 GA2  ?

Comment: Hi @PeterGrabowski, it's 7.3.10 GA1. I have adjusted the title to add this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for adding the portal version @Luke, I reproduced this issue using the same version now.
Then, after using the following resources, I managed to create a working app that overrides the update_password.jsp:
https://git.fortiss.org/civitas-digitalis/platform/-/tree/master/modules/UpdatePasswordOverride
https://www.softwaresavvyblog.com/post/liferay-overriding-core-jsps
I have created a repository with my working app, to show you how the code exactly looks like, it will print an "OVERRIDDEN" message to the top of the page when you visit:
http://localhost:8080/c/portal/update_password
My repository is located here:
https://github.com/peterpetrekanics/UpdatePwOverride7310

Here are my detailed steps I took:

1. Create a new Liferay workspace on your computer
   use  blade init  command from the terminal
   select dxp-7.3-sp1
2. Create an MVC Portlet project and remove the unnecessary files
3. Ensure that your build.gradle file contains this line:
   compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "release.portal.api"
   otherwise your class will not detect the import: com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.CustomJspBag;
4. Modify your class:
   add  "implements CustomJspBag"   after your class' name
5. Implement unimplemented methods (this is the part where using Liferay Developer Studio may come handy)
   I used the earlier mentioned blog resources for that.
6. Build the project and deploy it to a running 7.3 GA1 server
7. Visit this page, and the overridden message should appear:
   http://localhost:8080/c/portal/update_password

   I hope this helped, please let me know if you get other results

Comment: Thank you very much Peter, this was surely clear and helpful!